# How to modify Jake's resume template for Chinese characters?

Tags: overleaf, templates, chinese

Jake's resume is a famous resume template, its link is https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jakes-resume/syzfjbzwjncs

I want to modify it for Chinese characters, for example, change `\section{Education}` to `\section{教育经历}`.

Following overleaf's official guide, I changed `\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}` to `\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{ctexart}`. However, it cannot be compiled.

I tried all four compilers. pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTex all gave `NO PDF` error. LaTex didn't give error but after compiling the pdf is blank.

Could anyone please tell me how to modify it?

Comment: I didn't try as you provided only an external link and no complete example, but you can try to change the chinese fonts used with `\documentclass[fontset=fandol]{ctexart}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the lines `\input{glyphtounicode}` and `\pdfgentounicode=1`, then compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. These lines need pdfLaTeX but it seems Overleaf has issues with the Chinese fonts when using pdfLaTeX (compiling it with pdfLaTeX works fine on my local distribution).

Comment: Thank you very much! After removing these two lines, it works fine with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX for `\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{ctexart}`