# Jake's resume cannot be compiled with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, xetex, luatex, overleaf, chinese

Jake's resume is a famous resume template, its link is https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jakes-resume/syzfjbzwjncs

I want to modify it for Chinese characters, for example, change `\section{Education}` to `\section{教育经历}`.

I asked a question before [How to modify Jake's resume template for Chinese characters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651853/how-to-modify-jakes-resume-template-for-chinese-characters). And the answer suggests me to remove `\input{glyphtounicode}` and `\pdfgentounicode=1`, then compile it with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. However, today I found that this template cannot be compiled with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. It gives me `NO PDF` error in overleaf.

How should I fix it for my purpose?

Comment: Works for me in OL if switch to lualatex, then remove the two lines suggested, and then recompile.

Comment: @Thruston Thank you, but when I changed `\section{Education}` to `\section{教育经历}`, it shows a blank area.